# Error on regression test using "make check" on postgresql 11.0 in GridDB (FDW)

Tags: griddb

It cannot complete regression test using `make check` command. The issue occurs below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM department d, employee e 
WHERE d.department_id = e.emp_dept_id 
LIMIT 10;
```

> server closed the connection unexpectedly
> This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.
> connection to server was lost

This SQL query causes the error:

```
SELECT * 
FROM department d, employee e 
WHERE d.department_id = e.emp_dept_id 
LIMIT 10;
```

Following the log of the PostgreSQL server, I found out the error in `griddb_fdw.c`, line 857:

```
TRAP: FailedAssertion("!(fsstate->cursor == fsstate->num_tuples)", File: "griddb_fdw.c", Line: 857)
2018-12-26 15:45:56.052 +07 [5763] LOG:  server process (PID 5781) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2018-12-26 15:45:56.052 +07 [5763] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: 
SELECT * FROM department d, employee e WHERE d.department_id = e.emp_dept_id LIMIT 10;
```

The log of PostgreSQL server is attached: [postmaster.log](https://github.com/pgspider/griddb_fdw/files/2712156/postmaster.log)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged